# How to ignore a case and just keep summing while summing the values in an interval?

Tags: matlab

I have a value H , for example H=3 . I'm trying to sum for each t , c(t) of H items before (3 items before) and H items after (3 items after) time t. for example for t  , I expect to have:

```
    c(t-3) + c(t-2)+ c(t-1) + c(t) + c(t+1) + c(t+2) +c(t+3)
```

Here is the code which works perfectly :

```
    %just consider some values a C
    data = importdata('2.txt');  
    C = data.data.';
    C = C';

    N = length(C);
    H = 3;
    w = ones(2 * H + 1, 1);
    Lambda= NaN * zeros(N, 1);
    L= NaN * zeros(N, 1);
    U= NaN * zeros(N, 1);
    for t = (H+1):(N-H-1)
        Lambda(t) = sum(w .* C(t-H:t+H)) / sum(w);
        L(t) = poissinv(0.005, Lambda(t));
        U(t) = poissinv(0.995, Lambda(t));
    end
```

Now what I'm trying to do and I'm not successful is : I want NOT TO SUM C(t) in Lambda(t) average. I mean at the time t , I start summing the items from -H to H for each t , but not when H=t . I just want to ignore the case t=H and go on summing . 
I would really appreciate any advice as I'm new to MATLAB and I got stuck!

Comment: I'm confused.  You say you do not want to sum for the case `H=t`, but your loop over `t` begins at `t=H+1`, so `H` can never equal `t` anyway.

Comment: I don't mean in the for loop I mean in the sum function where I have C(t-H:t+H) I don't want to include the c(t) in this loop. for each t , I want to sum c in an interval of -H to +H where I meet also c(t). is it clear now or I'm failed to explain?

Comment: You can explicitly use a concatenation of indices that excludes `t` as in `C([ (t-H):(t-1) (t+1):(t+H) ])`

Comment: @sed it's a bright idea but I don't know why I get an error:product: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 7x1, op2 is 6x1) for Lambda.

Comment: you have to modify the `w` size to fit the size of `C`. For instance `w = ones(2 * H , 1)`.

Comment: @sed It's just great , thanks a million :)

Comment: Have you tried leaving your code as is but changing `w` so that `w = ones(2 * H + 1, 1);` and then `w(H+1) = 0` ? That way you multiply `C(t)` by `0` so it's not included in your sum... then you don't need to worry about making any other changes at all (but I'd still use convolution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't look at your code thoroughly but what you're describing sounds like basic convolution:

So ignoring `w` (which I think is just a multiplication of a constant? i.e. `1/6`?)

```
kernel = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1];
Lambda = conv(C, [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], 'same')
```

Convolution shifts `kernel` against `C` and takes a sum or the elementwise product of the overlapping elements. So to sum the three elements before and after we just multiply by one and to leave off the central element (i.e. `C(t)`) we just multiply by zero so that it doesn't contribute to the sum.

I think for using `w` you could just go

```
kernel = kernel/sum(kernel)    %//i.e. divide by 6 which is the same as 2*H
```

Also you to make it generalized rather define `kernel` like this:

```
kernel = ones(2 * H + 1, 1)/(2*H);
kernel(H+1) = 0;
```

So now you complete (vectorized!) code is:

```
data = importdata('2.txt');  
C = data.data;
H = 3;

kernel = ones(2 * H + 1, 1)/(2*H);
kernel(H+1) = 0;

Lambda = conv(C, kernel, 'same');
L = poissinv(0.005, Lambda);
U = poissinv(0.995, Lambda);
```

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer now I'll try it this way . But w is some how a weight , now just to make it simple I've considered it as 1 , and when w=1 it is obviously equal to the number of elements which we are summing.

Comment: @singu if you change `w` this will still work, it does the same thing as your code. Just edit kernel to be what your `w` is. For example weighting the near neighbors more: `kernal = [0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0, 0.6, 0.3, 0.1]`. Your loops are just reimplementing convolution anyway...

Comment: when I run this code under my for loop , which I have included at the question , I suppose to not have values for the last and first items because I don't have 3 values before or after them! but this code generates values even for first and last items . I'm trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Now I've checked another time this code , despite the problem which I told you in the upper comment , it's perfect . Thank you :)